# Declaring intersecting types in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings, tsc

I've started learning typescript from the official documentation, and came across the topic of intersecting types. So, in order to get a proper understanding of how type intersection works, i decided to write up a custom type. The FoodItems interface requires to be an array of objects and same for side. However, whenever I try intersect the two types, every representation of FoodOrder fails. I don't understand why that happens and what i'm doing wrong.

```
interface FoodItems {
   [index: number]: {name: string, quantityPerOrder: number};
}

interface FoodSide {
    [index: number]: {sideName: string, sideQuantity: number};
}

let foodItem: FoodItems = [{name: "Fried Chiken", quantityPerOrder: 2}, {name: "Burger", quantityPerOrder: 1}];
let foodSide: FoodSide = [{sideName: "gravy", sideQuantity: 1}];

type FoodOrder = FoodItems & FoodSide;

let food: FoodOrder;
```

The declaration 
 `let food: FoodOrder = [[{name: "Fried Chiken", quantityPerOrder: 2}],[{sideName: "gravy", sideQuantity: 1}]];` 
 gives me the following error:

```
index.ts:14:24 - error TS2322: Type '[{ name: string; quantityPerOrder: number; }]' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; quantityPerOrder: number; } & { sideName: string; sideQuantity: number; }'.
  Type '[{ name: string; quantityPerOrder: number; }]' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; quantityPerOrder: number; }'.

14 let food: FoodOrder = [[{name: "Fried Chiken", quantityPerOrder: 2}],[{sideName: "gravy", sideQuantity: 1}]];
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

index.ts:14:70 - error TS2322: Type '[{ sideName: string; sideQuantity: number; }]' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; quantityPerOrder: number; } & { sideName: string; sideQuantity: number; }'.
  Type '[{ sideName: string; sideQuantity: number; }]' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; quantityPerOrder: number; }'.

14 let food: FoodOrder = [[{name: "Fried Chiken", quantityPerOrder: 2}],[{sideName: "gravy", sideQuantity: 1}]];
```

Comment: just do `type FoodOrder = FoodItems | FoodSide` cause & will combine them into one (as in all 4 properties are required), while | will make i so it's one or the other

Comment: Intersection of types FoodItems and FoodSide is a set of objects with zero elements, so you can't assign anything to it. You probably wanted a union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *intersection type* requires `food` to be *both* a valid `FoodItems` object *and* a valid `FoodSide` object.

Remember: an *intersection type `I = A & B`* means that the set of values of type `I` is the *intersection* of the sets of the values of types `A` and `B`. Since every value of type `I` is *at the same time* a valid `A` and a valid `B`, it follows that the *properties* of the intersection type `I` must be the *union* of the properties of the types `A` and `B`.

Likewise, a *union type `U = A | B`* means that the set of values of type `U` is the *union* of the sets of the values of types `A` and `B`. Since every value of type `U` is *either* a valid `A` *or* a valid `B`, it follows that the *properties* of the union type `U` must be the *intersection* of the properties of the types `A` and `B`.

So, what you are saying is that `FoodOrder` is a type which can be indexed by a number and it returns a `FoodItems` but *at the same time* it also returns a `FoodSide` when it is indexed by a number.

A value of such a type cannot exist, so you actually can't construct anything that would be legal to assign to `food`.

What *would* be possible is something like this:

```js
interface FoodItem {
    name:             string
    quantityPerOrder: number
}

interface FoodSide {
    sideName:         string
    sideQuantity:     number
}

interface FoodOrder {
  [index: number]: FoodItem & FoodSide
}

let food: FoodOrder;

food = [
    {
        name:             "Fried Chiken", 
        quantityPerOrder: 2, 
        sideName:         "gravy", 
        sideQuantity:     1
    }
];
```